# Add Date from Source A to Source B

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have two OLE DB Source for an Excel file with two different sheet.
Sheet A and Sheet B.
Sheet A cell I6 contained the date, and I would like combine the two sources and add a column in Sheet B to set the value as Sheet A's Date value. Is it possible to do that? Any ideas would be helpful, thank you!

I tried to create the same column in each sources in order to UNION ALL Sheet A and Sheet B, but it did not return the way I wanted.

**Sheet A (consider this is their membership sign up date)**

| Date |
| --- |
| 2012-09-01 |

**Sheet B**

| Name | phone number |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 123345678 |
| David | 123345678 |
| Mary | 123345678 |

**Ideal Result**

| Name | phone number | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 123345678 | 2012-09-01 |
| David | 123345678 | 2012-09-01 |
| Mary | 123345678 | 2012-09-01 |

Comment: 1. Use this method to read the single vslue into a variable https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UYDvldSnuE0 2. Now use a datacopy to copy the file, but add a calculated column that is your variable that you set in step 1. But really SSIS is not the right tool for this.

Comment: An alternative method would be to have 2 sources in your data flow and the join the data from those sources on an arbitrary value (which you could create using a derived column transformation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only one date, It is better to store it in a date variable first:

1. Create a new variable, and assign the date: 01.09.2012

[image: Create Variable]

2.Add a derived Column Transformation in DFT, and set the new column called 'Date' equal to the variable defined in step1:

[image: Pipelines]

[image: DerivedColumn]

3. Finally Send it to OLEDB destination:

[image: Destionation]

Answer (score 0):

According to my testing in SSIS, you can done it by these steps:

1. OLE DB Source for Sheet A: Configure an OLE DB Source to read data from Sheet A. The key field here is the date.
2. Excel Source for Sheet B: Configure another Excel Source to read data from Sheet B.
3. Data Conversion for Sheet A: Because Excel data is usually imported as DT_WSTR, you may need to use a Data Conversion transformation to convert the date from Sheet A into a format that SSIS can handle (DT_DATE).
4. Recordset Destination for Sheet A: Use a Recordset Destination to store the single row of data from Sheet A (the date) in an SSIS Variable. You can create a new Object variable for this purpose.
5. Script Component as Transformation for Sheet B: For the Excel Source of Sheet B, add a Script Component acting as a transformation. In this Script Component, you can add a new output column (for the date), and set its value to the date from the variable (that stored the date from Sheet A). You would use the Row. *= Variables.* syntax in the Input0_ProcessInputRow method.
6. OLE DB Destination: Finally, you can write the data (now including the date from Sheet A) to your desired destination using an OLE DB Destination.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I wonder if you have any sample of the script? As I've never learn C# before.

Comment: Or by any chance there is a way to do it with SQL query in SSIS / SQL Server instead of C#?